# Prove that image don't construct $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a map and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra.

I know that class of all sets $B\subset Y$ that $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{A}$ is $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$, where $\mathcal{B} = \{ B \subset Y : f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A} \}$.

However class $ \{ f(A): A\in\mathcal{A} \} \subset2^Y $ is not a $\sigma$-algebra in genereal but I am not able to find good counterexample, a function $f$ to prove it.

Comment: What if $f$ is not surjective?

Comment: This is my try. Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ $X=[0, \infty]$, $Y=[0, \infty]$, $f(x)=2x$ (e.g. f([0,5])=[0,10]) , then i think that $\mathcal{A}=\{ \emptyset, [0,5], [5, \infty), [0, \infty) \}$. For $f([0,5])=[0,10]$ set $[0, 10]$ belongs to the class but it's complement $(10,\infty)$ do not belong to the class. Am I right or it is wrong idea?

Comment: Looks wrong. ${\cal A}$ is a simple $\sigma$-algebra and the class generated by this $f$ is $\{\emptyset,[0,10],[10,\infty),[0,\infty)\}$ - a  $\sigma$-algebra. What @TorstenSchoeneberg means is when $f$ is not surjective there is no set $A$ in $X$ such that $f(A)=Y.$ Such an $f$ never generates a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: BTW: $\mathcal{A}=\{ \emptyset, [0,5],\color{red}{(}5, \infty), [0, \infty) \}$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{ \emptyset, [0,10],\color{red}{(}10, \infty), [0, \infty) \}$ looks better.

Comment: Ok, so maybe $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}, X=[0,\infty], Y=[0,\infty], \mathcal{A}$- is a mentioned $\sigma$-algebra.Because f is not surjective there is not any x that $f(x)=0$. Is it right?

Comment: Again $X=\color{red}{(}0,\infty\color{red}{)}$ is better. With your previous $X$, $f$ is surjective! *Any* non surjective $f:X\to Y$ does the job. For example $f(x)=\arctan x$. Pick your favourite.

Comment: Simpler counter-example: Let $Y= \{y_1, y_2\} $ where $y_1 \neq y_2$. Take $f$ to be a constant function such that $f(x)=y_1$ for all $x \in X$. Then $\{ f(A): A\in\mathcal{A} \}=\{ \emptyset,\{y_1\}\}$ which is not a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. In fact, $\{ \emptyset,\{y_1\}\}$ is not closed by complement on $Y$.